# In gvim setting font size to 12 is not permanent and it is reverting back to 10 when I open gvim again

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, fonts, gvim

I am using Xubuntu 16.04

In gvim, by going to **Edit** ---> **Select font** I am selecting the **font size 12**. But after I close gvim and open gvim again I see that the **font size** has gone back to **10**.

How can I set the **font size** to **12** permanently?

Comment: Gvim is configured by settings in configuration files *which you are supposed to edit yourself*. It does not automatically update them. Use `:help initialization` in Gvim for details. You may also want to read `:help mkvimrc` and `:help mksession`. Simple answer is to add `set guifont Ubuntu\ Mono\ 13` or similar to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: vim ~/.vimrc produces a blank file

Comment: So read `:help mkvimrc` and make a new one.

Comment: In which location should I make the file

Comment: In your $HOME; exactly as you already begun -- `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Error detected while processing /home/saptak/.vimrc:    line 1:       E518: Unknown option: Ubuntu\ Mono\ 12       Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: Sorry, `set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 13`. Missing `=` sign in previous comment.

Comment: Now getting the error:  Error detected while processing /home/saptak/.vimrc:    line    1:    E492: Not an editor command: guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 13     Press ENTER or type command to continue

Answer (score 1):

You can set the GVim font in either your `~/.vimrc`, or in `~/.gvimrc` using:

```
set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 13
```

However, if you use `~/.vimrc`, then you need to ensure that it is only run for GVim, and not for regular command-line Vim:

```
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2")
   set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 13
  endif
endif
```

See [`:h 'guifont'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27guifont%27) for more.

Comment: adding "guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 13" to ~/.gvimrc makes vim font bigger, but gvim font is still small

Comment: and yes it is not a typo, editing ~/.gvimrc makes vim font bigger, not gvim

Comment: @Sonevol how exactly are you running Vim? Vim running in a terminal has no way to change the font or the font size.

Comment: For example there is sample.txt, to open in vim I give the command vim sample.txt and to open in gvim I give the command gvim sample.txt

Comment: I am using XFCE terminal

Comment: Don't know  how but it seems that now the problem has been solved, both vim and gvim has now large fonts. Please edit your answer  to include both vim and gvim. Then I can accept the answer

Comment: @Sonevol I cannot reproduce what you're seeing, so, sorry, I won't update it.